# Creating Sub Directories with harishanchu/Laravel-FTP

Tags: php, laravel-5, ftp

I am using harishanchu/Laravel-FTP.

I am trying to create sub directories like this but it isn't working

`FTP::connection()->makeDir('directory-name/sub-directory');`

Works fine for single directory

`FTP::connection()->makeDir('directory-name');`

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Because a directory name can't have a `/` in it, so `directory-name/sub-directory` is invalid as a directory name; and the `makeDir()` function isn't clever enough to treat this as a directory and subdirectory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move to the directory before you can create a sub-directory:

```
if (FTP::connection()->changeDir('directory-name')->makeDir('sub-directory')) {
    echo "directory made";
}
```

Comment: So in my array I'll have to navigate through each folder creating them on the new server until I get to the file and then upload it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You won't be able to create sub-directories in folders without being in the folder itself. Limitation of FTP commands.

Comment: Your question is related to creating a directory not uploading a file. Please post a new question with your second problem.